# Steps to be followed to run vault as a service( vault starts when the server starts ) also the root token needs to be permanent?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have followed many pages , that asked to write the service file. But each time the server is initialized, it triggers a new root token. Vault needs to be installed in a production environment and root token should be always the same as our application uses it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are running Vault in Dev mode, with the [*-dev* switch](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/dev-server.html)...?

You need to initialise permanently with [*vault operator init*](https://www.vaultproject.io/intro/getting-started/deploy.html).

Also, your application should not use the root token - use [App Roles](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle.html) to authenticate your app.

Answer (score 1):

First, get a Consul Backend in place.

Add this file to `/etc/vault.d/vault.hcl`:

```
storage "consul" {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
  path    = "vault/"
}

listener "tcp" {
 address     = "127.0.0.1:8200"
 tls_disable = 1
}
```

The `storage "consul" {` "stanza" tells Vault to use Consul as a back-end.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/getting-started/deploy#configuring-vault

To install Consul, just follow the directions from HashiCorp:

> To install Consul, find the appropriate package for your system and
>   download it. Consul is packaged as a zip archive.
>
> After downloading Consul, unzip the package. Consul runs as a single
>   binary named consul. Any other files in the package can be safely
>   removed and Consul will still function.
>
> The final step is to make sure that the consul binary is available on
>   the PATH. See this page for instructions on setting the PATH on Linux
>   and Mac. This page contains instructions for setting the PATH on
>   Windows.
>
> Starting a local Consul instance takes only a few minutes. Just follow the Consul > Getting Started Guide up to the point where you have installed Consul and started > it with this command:
>
> $ consul agent -dev

After you have Consul, there are publicly available SystemD unit files available that you can install.

If you have a Consul back-end in place, I've used something like the following when I want Vault to "start when the server starts":

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo bash -c "cat >/etc/systemd/system/vault.service" << 'EOF'
[Unit]
Description=SystemD Vault Service
[Service]
Restart=on-failure
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/sbin/setcap 'cap_ipc_lock=+ep' /usr/local/bin/vault
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/vault server -config /etc/vault.d
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillSignal=SIGTERM
User=vault
Group=vault
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF

sudo chmod 0664 /etc/systemd/system/vault*
```

https://github.com/v6/super-duper-vault-train/blob/develop/vaultsystemd.sh#L4-L20

For further reading, though, I recommend doing your own research to find something to fit your use case:

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vault+systemd+scripts

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vault-tool/E6Ny7SKx5x0

Finally, if you want to try out a cluster with Vault and Consul running in non `-dev` mode, I not-so-humbly recommend trying out the Vagrantfile I've been using:

https://github.com/v6/super-duper-vault-train#vagrant